# EXPLAINE : Highstock Displaying 1.7 million data points in Highcharts Stock

Tags: javascript, json, charts, highcharts

Hello everyone i'm a beginner in **highstock** 
i want to work with this to convert my data to graph 
then i find some problem in this example of [Lazy Loading](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/lazy-loading)
i have much question : 
need to change this [highstock](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/lazy-loading/) to my data just use a simple data 
like this :

```
[883612800000,3.41,5.01,3.37,4.58],
[886291200000,4.62,5.97,4.34,5.91],
[888710400000,5.89,7.01,5.40,6.88],
[891388800000,6.87,7.41,6.17,6.85],
[893980800000,6.88,7.91,6.42,6.68],
[896659200000,6.61,7.24,6.39,7.16],
[899251200000,7.22,9.54,7.12,8.67],
[901929600000,8.56,10.92,7.75,7.80],
[904608000000,7.84,10.05,7.65,9.52],
[907200000000,9.19,10.33,7.12,9.28],
[909878400000,9.39,9.85,7.94,7.99],
[912470400000,8.00,10.37,7.90,10.23],
[915148800000,10.53,11.82,9.27,10.29],
[917827200000,10.42,10.48,8.63,8.71]`
```

then in the same example i want a method how to removed the **zoom** and the **scroll** in the bottom 
and in last 
need to sample exampling about this function

```
function afterSetExtremes(e) {

    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();

    chart.showLoading('Loading data from server...');
    $.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/from-sql.php?start=' + Math.round(e.min) +
            '&end=' + Math.round(e.max) + '&callback=?', function (data) {

            chart.series[0].setData(data);
            chart.hideLoading();
        });
}
```

> ** in the end thanks for all and sorry for my bad english any confused ask in commentaire **

Comment: You can disable [navigator](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#navigator.enabled) / [scrollbar](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#scrollbar.enabled) / [zoom](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#chart.zoomType)

Comment: Thanks mr @SebastianBochan for replay 
can you modified [this](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/lazy-loading/)
i want to removed to my the zoom then the scroll in bottom , i want just a graph with one year without all this astuce

Comment: Something like http://jsfiddle.net/g595mafq/ ?

Comment: yeah nearly but still know how to remove the zoom and show just the year one year :/ 
did you know what is the function of this _afterSetExtremes(e)_

Comment: I advice you to visit [docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock) and  [Highstock definition](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/understanding-highstock)

Comment: this is a week and 2 days i read this docs and everything's but nothing new  i have experience in all highchart but this highstock nervous  me

Comment: So what is unclear? afterSetExtremes is an event which is called when range on chart is changed.

Comment: me i have just a simple tables with million datas 
** ID | TIME | DATA **
i want to use this graph but , in there exemple don't explain how to take data from  local and give it to chart , this example working with server , can you make form me a example in rar with 10 or 50 rows and a tables  like my , and me i want to change the query and the tables my and add or remove the astuce from chart :)

Comment: You cannot load form filesystem (security reasons in browsers) so you need to have a webserver. Read an article how to [load data and process](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/custom-preprocessing)

Comment: thanks sir i will see it :D
can post any answer i chose like a :true_answer: to close this topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot load form filesystem (security reasons in browsers) so you need to have a webserver. Please check our article how to [load data and process](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/custom-preprocessing)